# C# SQL CLR - convert SqlString to String

Tags: c#, sql-server, string, sqlclr

This works but I want to convert `SqlString` to `String` and do `String.Length`. If `String.Length` is e.g. 5, I want to display in cell (in table in SQL Server) e.g. Active, but if not, I want to display the current field value.

```
public class proveraMb
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
    public static SqlString matbr (SqlString ispravan)
    {
        SqlString i = ispravan;

        if (i == "ss")
            return i;
        else
            return "nije dobar";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call the [ToString() method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqltypes.sqlstring.op_explicit?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_SqlTypes_SqlString_op_Explicit_System_Data_SqlTypes_SqlString__System_String)

Sample

```
SqlString i = ispravan;
string test = i.ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

While the `ToString()` method does work, it is better to use (and get used to using) the `Value` property. The reason that this is better is that *all* `Sql*` types have a `Value` property that returns the expected native .NET type. So `SqlInt64.Value` returns a `long`, `SqlDateTime.Value` returns a `DateTime`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Each `SqlType` has a `Value` property. This property gives you back the value of the `SqlType` cast to the native type.